# Construct a perpendicular to a given line from a given (external) point, using a compass only once

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Given a line $AB$ and a point $C$ not on $AB$ it is easy enough to construct a perpendicular line to $AB$ passing through $C$ using two circles as demonstrated in the following picture.

[image: perpendicular line construction]

Here we pick two arbitrary points $E$ and $F$ on $AB$ and draw circles with centres $E$ and $F$ and radii $EC$ and $FC$. Then we take the two points of intersection of these circles (one of which is $C$) and draw a line between them. This gives a perpendicular line to $AB$ passing through $C$.

A similar proof is given in [Euclid's Elements](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookI/propI12.html) which uses the same idea and constructs two circles.

> I am interested to know if we can construct a perpendicular from a given point to given line using the compass just a single time.

Comment: yes. Walk over to a guy who knows how and say you will stab him with the compass unless he constructs the perpendicular.

Comment: @Will Jagy I appreciate. I would call this method "compass only construction under constraint."

Comment: @Will, with that method you might even not use the compass!

Comment: @Mariano, true. Note that Jack answered with no explicit threats.

Comment: Well, he knows what is best for him...

Answer (score 8):

*Yes we can*! By exploiting the properties of orthocentric systems.

[image]

1. Let $\Gamma$ be a small circle centered at $O\in\ell$, let $AB$ be its diameter on $\ell$;
2. Let $C=PA\cap\Gamma$ and $D=PB\cap\Gamma$. Since $\widehat{ADB}=\widehat{ACB}=90^\circ$...
3. By defining $E=AD\cap BC$ we have that $E$ is the orthocenter of $ABP$, hence...
4. $PE\perp \ell$ as wanted.

*Please don't stab me*.

Comment: Beautiful. ${}$

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio [+1] I was blocked by the fact that I wasn't on the track of a construction with a compass **and a ruler**. But anyhow, I wouldn't have thought to this clever construction !

Comment: @JeanMarie right, I thought if a straightedge were permitted it would have been mentioned.

Comment: @WillJagy: I guessed the perpendicular had to be drawn somehow :D

Comment: Jack, that is the kind of clear thinking that will take you far.

Comment: @WillJagy: there should be a bit of your humour in everybody's life :D